# What is the formula to obtain the derivative of a function?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I have a Casio calculator that can do Differential Calculations. In the manual, it said:

> The procedure described below obtains the derivative of a function.
> Three inputs are required for the differential expression: the
> function of variable `x`, the point (`a`) at which the differential
> coefficient is calculated, and the change in `x` (delta x).
>
> Calculate_Differential ( `expression`, `a`, `delta x`)
>
> Example: To determine the derivative at point `x=2` for the function
> `y= 3*x^2 - 5*x + 2`, when the increase or decrease in `x` is `delta x = 2E-4`: The Result is `7`
>
> Note:
>
> - You can omit input of `delta x`, if you want. The calculator automatically substitutes an appropriate value for `delta x` if you do
>   not input one.
> - Discontinuous points and extreme changes in the value of `x` can cause inaccurate results and errors.

My problem is I can't figure out what is the formula behind the `Calculate_Differential`, I have read [this wikipedia page about Derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative) but I totally lost. I need something practical to understand, **for example**: to calculate Numerical Integration with Simpson's Rule, this kind of explanation I can understand:

> Given an interval [a, b] and an even number n, Simpson’s rule
> approximates the integral
>
> [image: Integral]
>
> by **(This is the formula I need)**
>
> [image: Integral formula]
>
> where `h = (b - a)/n` and `x[i] = a + i*h`.

So what is the formula to obtain the derivative of a function so that I can apply the `expression (e.g: 3*x^2 - 5*x + 2)`, the point `a (e.g: 2)`, the `delta x (e.g: 2E-4)`, to obtain the `result (e.g: 7)`.

Also, in the Note of the calculator, there are some points I don't understand:

- "The calculator automatically substitutes an appropriate value for `delta x`": what value can be considered appropriate for `delta x`?
- "Discontinuous points and extreme changes in the value of `x` can cause inaccurate results and errors.": It means "If `delta x` is to big then the function is wrong"?

Comment: It appears that the way the calculator calculates derivatives at a point $x=a$ is by simply finding $\frac{f(a+\Delta x)-f(a)}{\Delta x}$. So it just uses a "really small" value for $\Delta x$. If the function has extreme changes, the $\Delta x$ may not be small enough to get an accurate value for the derivative.

Comment: @Bonnaduck - I suspect that's the formula behind, too. But when I apply that formula, the result it gives is `7.0006` instead of `7`. I can't figure out why it round up like that so I thought maybe there's another formula or something I'm missing.

Comment: For derivatives you take $h \rightarrow 0$. For finite $h$ you are only *approximating* the derivative. Hence the approximation error of $0.0006$. Probably you need to take $h$ small enough so that the error is smaller than the precision of the calculator. This may be $10^{-16}$ ? You could read about that in the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So [this is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/373265) the formula:

(The centered three-point method):

> `[f(x+h) - f(x-h)] / 2h`
>
> where h is a small number

Or this formula (centered five-point method) works too:

> [f(x-2h) - 8f(x-h) + 8f(x+h) - f(x+2h)] / 12h
>
> where h is a small number

So when I apply x=2, h=2E-4, f="3*x^2 - 5*x + 2". It gives me 7.

I still need to figure out what is the appropriate value for `h`.

Comment: What happens if you evaluate the derivative of $|x|$ at $x=0$? If the result is $0$, then that is good evidence that the calculator uses one of these formulas. Even better, check $x=0.2$ and see if the value around $0.2$. If so, that would be *very* good evidence.

Comment: @Bonnaduck - If I understand correctly |x| means change negative (if any) to positive. So I enter the `f="x",x=0,h=1E-5`: both the calculator and "centered five-point method" return 1 (result's not 0). Then I enter `f="x",x=0.2,h=1E-5`: both the calculator and "centered five-point method" return 1 (result's not around 0.2). So both the calculator and the "centered five-point method" matches result, but not matches your expected result, Do I understand your test correctly?

Comment: No, that won't work. Instead, use the function $\sqrt{x^2}$, making sure the $x^2$ is inside the square root.

Comment: @Bonnaduck - So I enter the `f="√(x²)",x=0,h=1E-5`: both the calculator and "centered five-point method" return 0 (your expect result is right in this case). Then I enter `f="√(x²)",x=0.2,h=1E-5`: both the calculator and "centered five-point method" return 1 (result's not around 0.2). So again, both the calculator and the "centered five-point method" matches result. But it doesn't match your expected result in case x=0.2.

Comment: I’m not sure what I was thinking about $x=0.2$. Okay, the fact that it gave a (incorrect) derivative of $0$ at $x=0$ is good evidence that the calculator is using one of these methods.